# Lambda function returns different output from direct code

Tags: python, pandas

I am checking for a condition of the difference between two values is 0.5 **AND** if they occurred on different dates, then it's a flag.

Sample Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date1' : ['2023-05-11', '2023-02-24', '2023-07-9', '2023-01-19', '2023-02-10'],
                  'date2' : ['2023-05-11', '2023-02-24', '2023-07-8', '2023-01-17', '2023-02-10'],
                  'value1' : [9.11, .12, 49.1, 2.25, 6.22],
                  'value2' : [2.12, .86, 0.03, .17, 4.71]})

df
    date1       date2       value1  value2
0   2023-05-11  2023-05-11  9.11    2.12
1   2023-02-24  2023-02-24  0.12    0.86
2   2023-07-09  2023-07-08  49.1    0.03
3   2023-01-19  2023-01-17  2.25    0.17
4   2023-02-10  2023-02-10  6.22    4.71

df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date1'])
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'])
```

When I try with `apply` function:

```
df.apply(lambda x : 'yes' if (abs(x['value1'] - x['value2']) > .5) & (x['date1'].date != x['date2'].date) else 'no', axis = 1)

0    yes
1    yes
2    yes
3    yes
4    yes
dtype: object
```

Without `apply` function:

```
(abs(df['value1'] - df['value2']) > .5) & (df['date1'].dt.date != df['date2'].dt.date)

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4    False
dtype: bool
```

As we can see above, the direct approach without `apply` function is giving expected output, whereas the apply function is not. Could you please let me know why is that the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For same output dd `()` for dates, because use [`Timestamp.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.date.html), not [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
#if omit () get built methods
print (df.apply(lambda x : x['date1'].date, axis = 1))
 0    <built-in method date of Timestamp object at 0...
 1    <built-in method date of Timestamp object at 0...
 2    <built-in method date of Timestamp object at 0...
 3    <built-in method date of Timestamp object at 0...
 4    <built-in method date of Timestamp object at 0...
 dtype: object

#get dates
print (df.apply(lambda x : x['date1'].date(), axis = 1))
0    2023-05-11
1    2023-02-24
2    2023-07-09
3    2023-01-19
4    2023-02-10
dtype: object

df.apply(lambda x : (abs(x['value1'] - x['value2']) > .5) &
                    (x['date1'].date() != x['date2'].date()), axis = 1)
```

Better is your second vectorized approach:

```
(abs(df['value1'] - df['value2']) > .5) & (df['date1'].dt.date != df['date2'].dt.date)
```

If need return `yes/no`:

```
np.where((abs(df['value1'] - df['value2']) > .5) & (df['date1'].dt.date != df['date2'].dt.date), 'yes', 'no')

df.apply(lambda x : 'yes' if (abs(x['value1'] - x['value2']) > .5) & (x['date1'].date() != x['date2'].date()) else 'no', axis = 1)
```

EDIT: If working with boolean, `&` and `and` working same, thanks @Mustafa Aydın for comment:

> `and` is clearer to use in Boolean and'ings than `&` because latter is mainly for bitwise-and in pure Python and overloaded for vectorized-and in NumPy (and pandas)

```
print (True and True)
True
print (False and True)
False
print (True and False)
False
print (False and False)False

print (True & True)
True
print (False & True)
False
print (True & False)
False
print (False & False)
False
```

Comment: Could you please explain why to use `and` in `apply` functions instead of `&`

Comment: @KarthikS - Answer was edited. `and` tests whether both expressions are logically True while `&` (when used with True/False values) tests if both are True.

Comment: @KarthikS you forgot parens, i.e., `.date()` instead of `.date` so you were comparing method objects instead of Timestamps. For Booleans, `&` and `and` do the exact same thing, so if you only change `.date()` parts, your code will work. jezrael's explanation above is misleading and wrong. That being said, `and` is clearer to use in Boolean and'ings than `&` because latter is mainly for bitwise-and in pure Python and overloaded for vectorized-and in NumPy (and pandas).

Comment: @MustafaAydın - thank you for comment, now it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

`df.apply(lambda x : 'yes' if (abs(x['value1'] - x['value2']) >0.5) & (x['date1'] != x['date2']) else 'no', axis = 1)`

`0      :   no

1     :  no

2   :  yes

3   : yes

4    : no`

This is the correct applying lamda function for correct answer